Is assumption that it is easier to add qubits to quantum annealer than general quantum computer outdated assumption?
In november 2025 IBM will have quantum computer with about 4 000 qubits. After that it is highly possible that within a few years qubit count will be in a limit of their new architecture that is about 100k qubits.
At the same time D-Wave have used many years to advance their machine from about 5000 to 7000 qubits.
General assumption so far have been that quantum annealer is easier technology and it is thus easier to add more qubits into it. Is that still the case? If not what have been changed?

Typically we want to add qubits while at least maintaining similar levels of connectivity and noise (but ideally improving them). So keeping that in mind, although IBM claims that they will reach 400 qubits next year, and ultimately 100k in the not so distant future, I think this question will have a clearer answer when (imo) we see what they (and D-Wave) actually end up doing.

D-Wave produces quantum annealers, which are not universal quantum computers. Quantum annealers can only solve a very specific type of optimization problems. Because of that, the design of their hardware can be optimized specifically for the optimization problems without needing to support the broader range of quantum control operations required by universal quantum computers.
